# asp.net website doesnt work with firefox 3.6

Tags: asp.net, firefox3.6, firefox-5

So I made a website, hosted it and it works fine on firefox 5.0
my friend tested it out, and he said it doesnt work for him, he is using firefox 3.6

the website is written in asp.net. I decided to test it out myself, and he was right. firefox 3.6 will not let me use the asp.net text box. project is in ASP.NET 4.0

any suggestions on how to fix it?

It seems to not only work for the login page which is my default, the rest seems to work.

is there a line of code I missed to input that makes it compatible?

<--------Edited-------->

I thought at first the text box isn't working, but its actually just looks like the front page is frozen, I cannot select the text box or the button.

this is the code, not sure if I need to include anything else.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
   <style type="text/css">

        body   
        {
            background: #D0D0D0;
            font-size: .80em;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            color: #696969;
            position:relative;
            z-index: -99;
        }
        /* Login Box */
        .login
        {
            background: #D0D0D0;
        }

        .container
        {
            background-image:url('newui/images/head.png');
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            width: 518px;
            height: 388px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-top: 90px;
        }
        .content
        {
            margin-left: 140px;
            margin-top: 70px;
        }

        .header
        {
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1#site-name
        {
            margin-top: 62px;

        }

        .button
        {
            margin-left: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div class="login">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="header">
                   <h1 id="site-name">
                        <font color="black" size="5">SES Users Admin</font>
                   </h1>
                </div>
                 <!--Hello Content -->
                <div class="content">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Height="21px" 
                            style="margin-left: 2px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="20px" 
                            style="margin-left: 4px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="button">
                        <asp:label id="lblResult" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:label>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" 
                                Width="57px" Height="21px"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "firefox 3.6 will not let me use the asp.net text box"

Comment: I'm failing at imagining your code. Please edit your question and add more information/code as it clearly is impossible to answer your questions.

Comment: I updates the question, please review

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the generated HTML is valid.
2. Install Firefox 3.6 (locally or in a virtual machine).
3. Test the website.
4. Reproduce the error.
5. Fix it or come here with more details.
6. ???
7. Profit.

Comment: Error is still there, firebug doesnt give any errors, the front page just look like it froze, when clicking on it, its as if the textboxes and button are a part of an image. Have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Is the codebehind OK? Debugger stopped/crashed? Does the problem exists with other older versions of Firefox (e.g. 3.5)? What is the generated HTML markup like?

Comment: i fixed it, apparently the problem was firefox 3.6 doesnt support negative z-index.

Comment: Uh, maybe it supports it, but placed your `body` element *under* the `html` element, so you could not click it (just speculation).